# How can I improve the code for decoding the QR code in MatLab?

Tags: java, matlab, qr-code, zxing

I'm using a [wrap-up package](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29239-qr-code-encode-and-decode?focused=5170461&tab=function) of [Zxing's code](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) to decode the QR code in MatLab. I have 300 images with QR codes, but only 120 out of 300 can be read. When I tried [Zxing's decode site](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx), more codes can be read. I searched a bit and compared the codes I used in MatLab with the codes in [Zxing GitHub source code](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/zxingorg/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/web/DecodeServlet.java). I found a bit difference in the code as I showed below. Somebody also suggested that this change would make difference ([here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zxing/YtclgvwdXcs)). (I guess it's only adding a `new` before `BufferedImageLuminanceSource`. Right?)

I have no idea about Java. So I'm asking how can I improve the following steps in MatLab? I also saw in Zxing's source code, it uses many different methods to try to read the code. How can I add this to my MatLab code? If it's too much work to do, could somebody suggest me a link so that I can learn how to improve it myself?

From ExchangeFile for MatLab:

```
jimg = im2java2d(img);
source = BufferedImageLuminanceSource(jimg);
bitmap = BinaryBitmap(HybridBinarizer(source));
```

From Zxing's code:

```
    private static void processImage(BufferedImage image,
                                   HttpServletRequest request,
                                   HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(source));
    Collection<Result> results = new ArrayList<>(1);
```

I don't know whether it's right to put the codes from Zxing's GitHub and from FileExchange here. So if it's not right to do this, please tell me. Thanks you!

**Edit**

Maybe my question is not so clear. So to summarise my question: I found that some QR images failed to decode in the wrapper script in MatLab but can be read in the Zxing online decoder. What could be the reason for the different results, as the wrapper script in MatLab uses the same function as Zxing online decoder?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [this page](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing):

> **Just Need a JAR?**
>
> If you just need a pre-built JAR file, you can always find compiled
>   resources from the [Maven release repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/), including recent
>   snapshot/nightly builds.

Following the aforementioned link, you should be able to download the `jar` packages needed to run `ZXing`. The wrapper script you found on `Mathworks File Exchange` also points you to the same direction, look at the comment placed on the top of the `test_qr.m` file:

> % Please download and build the core and javase parts of zxing % from
>   here - http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

The original link is dead since `Google Code` has been shut down, but it redirects you to the same `GitHub` repository.

Once you have the `jar` files, place them into a folder together with the `Matlab` files belonging to the script. Make sure that the `javaaddpath` directives in `test_qr.m` properly point to the `jar` packages, and you should have everything to make the script work.

If the `jar` files you downloaded have been compiled under a different version than the one your Matlab installation uses (to check this just run the command `version -java` from your command window), things will become much more complicated since you have to download the source files of `ZXing` and compile them under the proper version within a `Java IDE` like `Eclipse`. But let's not discuss too much about this, since at presente we don't know if you will ever stumble upon this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks Tommaso for your answer! But I'm a bit confused now. Actually the the wrapper package in the File Exchange works in my MatLab, but not as well as Zxing online decoder. I mean the image failed to read in MatLab can be read by the online decoder. That's why I'm thinking to compare the code they are using, and improve the method in MatLab, as the wrapper script was created in 2010.

Comment: The main point here is that I think Zxing's decoder uses a better way to decode the QR code, which is updated recently, while the wrapper package in MatLab still used the old function, as it has not been updated since 2010. But I'm not sure whether what I think is right.

Comment: The problem is that a wrapper is just a wrapper. I mean, the only purpose of that script on file exchange is to make the Zxing package run under Matlab. It's not by improving the Matlab part that you can improve the Zxing output...

Comment: Yeah, exactly. So I don't mean to improve the MatLab part. Instead, I mean I would like to improve the wrapper script, which can be updated with Zxing's method. As you see in the DecodeServelet script of Zxing, it uses a new call there for the `BufferedImageLuminanceSource` function. (I'm not sure whether I understand correctly at this step.) So I'm thinking whether I can change the `BufferedImageLuminanceSource` call in wrapper script to the new call as it is in Zxing's DecodeServelet script. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: No I don't get it. The wrapper just uses an instance of BufferedImageLuminanceSource, which is defined in the Zxing source code. If you want to change the way BufferedImageLuminanceSource works, you have to change that java class in the Zxing source code, not the matlab script.

Comment: Hmm, how can I open the .jar file to see the codes in? In the site Zxing source code, it uses a call like `new BufferedImageLuminanceSource` while in the wrapper it's `BufferedImageLuminanceSource`. It's only a `new` different. In a google group question, somebody said adding a `new` in the call could improve the decoding. So one thing here I don't understand is whether `BufferedImageLuminanceSource` is different with `new BufferedImageLuminanceSource`? If so, is it defined in the Zxing's source code or in the wrapper code?